# Trace 301 Redirect Rule and move all request to www subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a domain example.com added to the DigitalOcean (Ubuntu 16.04) with Apache2.4.18 and have Wordpress installed on it. The site is running properly.

The problem is, that all the request `www.example.com` redirects to `example.com`. I need `example.com` to redirect to `www.example.com`.

I see there are 2 ways to do it. 1. `.htaccess` and 2. Apache config file, currently using `000-default.conf` file. I installed `letsencrypt` ssl, which added the following `RewriteRule` to `000-default.conf`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

based on the research online, I did modify the `000-default.conf` to

```
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

and also tried the following code in `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Upon doing either of these, I get error of `multiple redirection loop`. Which basically redirecting `example.com` to `www.example.com` and `www.example.com` to `example.com` and so on. I tested the same on [Redirectcheck.com](http://redirectcheck.com/).

The main issue is I can't seem to find out the first `301 Redirect` which is all the request being redirected to `exmple.com`. If I can disable or overwrite the main `301 Redirect` rule then I can achieve all the request to be redirected to `www.example.com`.

I did my research but I'm hitting my head hard here, any help would be really appreciated. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

So, I finally traced it down, all the configuration were correct, the only issue was in the WordPress -> Admin Panel -> Setting -> General. I have placed the `site_url` and `main_url` as `example.com` and when I updated it to `www.example.com` and tested again, It did fix it.